# Typescript decorators: How to force declaration?

Tags: typescript, decorator

The typescript documentation on class decorators is quite clear that decorators are ran at declaration and not at instantiation.

However, it seems that if a class is not explicitly instantiated, typescript optimises out the declaration entirely.

This creates a problem with my use case, as I'm trying to dynamically instantiate a Message class based on the metadata stored within the decorator.

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-yz95bc?file=index.ts

I thought it would be an elegant solution, but if I have to manually instantiate each class (and then throw it away) in order to get Typescript to include the class, it becomes a lot less elegant.

Is there another way to force Typescript to include the class decoration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, the import statements are being elided by Typescript because it considers them to be unused.

The fix is to import the classes with a **side effect import**.

So instead of `import { MessageOne } from './MessageOne'`, you do `import './MessageOne';`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ifb6v6?file=index.ts

Comment: In case you are looking for a official answer: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import-a-module-for-side-effects-only